# try.. except failing inside for loop

Tags: python-3.x, try-except, scipy-optimize

I have a `for loop` which loops through initial guesses for a `scipy.optimize.minimize` routine. Some of the initial guesses fail, so I want to wrap the call to `scipy.optimize.minimize` in a `try/except` statement, so that when a guess fails, it moves on to the next.

Unfortunately this is not working. Once a guess fails, the next iterations also fail, even if the initial guess is a good one that I know works.

When I try to reproduce this failure in a MWE, I can't, so I am stumped.

Here is the MWE that works

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    assert type(x) == float
    return np.log(x)

def arbitrary_function():
    vals = [ 0.5, "string", 5, 9.3]
    v_list=[]
    for num in vals:
        try:
            v = f(num)
            if v > 0:
                v_list.append(v)
        except:
            print("failed on {}".format(num))
            continue   
    return v_list

my_list = arbitrary_function()
print(my_list)
```

Am I missing something with the `try.. except` usage?

The error that the real code raises on the failed attempts is due to

```
assert np.isclose(np.sum(x_tilde), 1.0)

AssertionError
```

for this reason I included the `assert type(x) == float` in the MWE, it raises the same exception, however, it carries on fine after hitting `string`, whereas my actual code only does the exceptions following a failure.

The real code has inside the `try` statement, where I have `f(num)`

```
try:
    params = scipy.optimize.minimize(stuff)
    if params.success:
        stuff
except:
    continue
```

Maybe the `params.success` is throwing it off since that doesn't exist when the `scipy.optimize.minimize` fails in the middle?

It does not appear to even attempt to do `scipy.optimize.minimize` on the next iteration once one of the initial guesses has caused `scipy` to fail.

Comment: I run your code and don't get errors!?

Comment: @user1740577 That is correct, the MWE works, and that is the problem. It has the same form as my real problem, but works. My real code doesn't work, and I don't know why :S

Comment: why don't send your real code?!

Comment: because it is long and complicated and proprietary

Comment: Once an iteration causes the `try` to fail, the next iterations don't even bother calling `scipy.optimize.minimize`, but they will output print statements, meaning the code does go inside the `try` statement

Comment: any chance @hpaulj has any insight? when I ask for 5 hardcoded minimizations, rather than looping, this also fails. There is something here involving the scipy optimization such that once it fails, it can't be called again :S